# Вопрос про if в списке

Tags: python, list, if

Вкратце, такая задача:
есть список животных в зоопарке.
Если совпадает тип и разный гендер, то вывести i из animals

Такой код получился у меня:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
animals = f.readlines()

animal = []
for i in animals:
    animal.append([i])

animals = [animal[j][0].split(", ") for j in range(len(animal))]

types = []
gender = []
for i in animals:
     types.append(i[1])
     gender.append(i[2])
       if .........?:
       print(i)
```

Должен быть вывод:

```
['1', 'cat', 'male', 'goroh', '01.01.2012', '02.12.2015\n']
['3', 'cat', 'female', 'goroh', '01.01.2012', '02.12.2015\n']
['4', 'elephant', 'male', 'goroh', '01.01.2012', '02.12.2015\n']
['7', 'elephant', 'female', 'goroh', '01.01.2012', '02.12.2015']
```

Я сделал отдельные списки для гендера и типа, но не понимаю, что с ним дальше делать. Перепробовал разные условия. Если нужно, то могу добавить к коду. Но это будет просто посмеяться. Как реализовать такую задачу?

Текстовый файл:

```
1, cat, male, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
2, dog, male, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
3, cat, female, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
4, elephant, male, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
5, tiger, male, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
6, gepard, male, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
7, elephant, female, goroh, 01.01.2012, 02.12.2015
```

Comment: А что вы хотите получить на выходе? Если я правельно понял cat, elephant?

Comment: Да, верно. При условии, что у cat и elephant разные гендеры. А если бы, например, повторялся dog несколько раз, но у него был бы только гендер "male", то не выводить

Comment: ну, давайте показывайте, смеяться не будем

Comment: Я пробовал добавлять types = [k for k, v in Counter(types).items() if v > 1] (from collections import Counter
) и если количество элементов в нем больше 1, то выводить "i" (это совпадало бы хотя бы с первым условием), но так не получается, т.к. создается несколько списков. Либо я не так что-то делаю)

Comment: Получается примерно так:     a = [k for k, v in Counter(types).items() if v > 1]
    if len(a) > 1:
        print(i) но всё равно выводит не то

Answer (score 1):

Ну если ты знаешь, что у тебя максимум 1 пара животных, то мой код будет работать:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    animals = f.readlines()

    animal = []
    for i in animals:
        animal.append([i])

    animals = [animal[j][0].split(", ") for j in range(len(animal))]

    animals = sorted(animals, key=lambda x: x[1]) # сортируем животных по именам, чтобы если были 2 одинаковых, то они шли друг за другом
    oldAnimal = 'Тут должны быть не менее трёх любых символов'# тут просто создаём переменную, и чтобы компилятор не ругался на [1] или [2], делаем переменную строкой
    for animal in animals:
        if animal[1] == oldAnimal[1] and animal[2] != oldAnimal[2]:
            print(oldAnimal)
            print(animal)
        oldAnimal = animal
```